# Using pos option in chemnum changes the size of some labels

Tags: auto-pst-pdf, chemnum

I am using pos options to change the alignment of chemnum tags. However, it changes the size of the labels. It appears to negate the defined font size in the preamble. What options am I missing?

MWE eps file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ePJGhcUoorYQgAN_DR0A89RZFwWnIGtm/view?usp=sharing

MWE code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
\usepackage{tikz}
\fi
\setchemnum{
    replace-style = \fontsize{10}{12}\rmfamily
}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \replacecmpd[pos = rr]{A}
    \replacecmpd[pos = rr]{B}   
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{MWE2.eps}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

This is the output of the MWE. The font size of the first two labels are larger than what I define in the preamble.

[image: This is the output of the MWE. The font size of the first two labels are larger than what I define in the preamble.]

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've found a bug which is fixed in v1.3a. This MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: on, interaction: nonstopmode }
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\setchemnum{ replace-style = \color{red} }
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
  \centering
  \replacecmpd[pos = rr]{A}
  \replacecmpd[pos = rr]{B}
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{MWE2.eps}
  \par
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]